# ajax load json file not working in iOS uiwebview but working in safari

Tags: ios, ajax, json, uiwebview

I am writing a html used in iOS uiwebview to load a json file on a server in javascript. Following is the json data.

```
{"posts": {"post": [
    {
        "date": "2014-08-21",
        "id": "00e8fa3a41bb42f7be1997053830516b",
        "title": "abc",
        "content": "`w;lkjjfdsd;lkfadvn"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-09-03",
        "id": "20fe501e95994bfebe9f62abce99aa36",
        "title": "kl;jsdfja",
        "content": "lk;sdjfsafj"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-09-03",
        "id": "013cc71e4a424bc3826731711d69ca6e",
        "title": "def",
        "content": "defji"
    }
]}}
```

The ajax code I put is as follow. I can get the first alert popped up, but not the second one.  Any ideas? guys?

```
$.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: url,
                   dataType: 'json',
                   async: true,
                   crossDomain: true,
                   success: function(data) { alert(url); alert(data.posts.post[0].date); }

            });
```

iOS code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" ]];
    [_mWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

The issue is that if I run the html in safari, the ajax code works fine (two alerts popped up). But if I load this in UIWebview for iOS, it doesn't work. So I googled online about this issue and based on what I see it might be a cross domain issue (the index.html loaded in the web view is local, but the json it request is on the server). How can we make my code load data/file cross domain? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript console to catch and read error messages. I suggest enabling one by clicking F12 and retry the request.

Comment: Hi there, I am doing this for the iOS app (UIwebview) and I am quite new to this area. Could you please provide more detail about how/where to see the log in the console? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The function that reads data should be `success`, not `complete`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data) { alert(url); alert(data.posts.post[0].date); }
});
```

Comment: Hi Seb, change it to success won't even trigger the first alert. I guess that means my ajax doesn't get the data successfully. However, if I put my url into a browser, it returns me the json data in it. So I guess it is accessible. Any idea why is that? Thanks

Comment: Start the developer tools (F12) and look at the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: I am doing this for the iOS app (UIwebview) and I am quite new to this area. Could you please provide more detail about how/where to see the error(s)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are saying "If I put my url into a browser": the console and developer tools are usually provided with the browser (F12 on Firefox, Safari:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) But I guess your case is different. I am not familiar at all with iOS development, sorry.

Comment: HI Seb. Thanks for your help. It turns if I run the page in safari, it works fine but in iOS web view, I have this trouble. So obviously, not ajax code problem. Do you have any idea why is that? Many thanks.